# How to define a constant in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I have tried almost every possibility of defining a constant in my sql:

```
variable id;
datatype NUMBER;
```

does not work. Neither does

```
variable:=2;
```

work. Same goes for

```
declare variable number;
begin
   variable:=2;
end
```

It can't be this hard, can it?

Edit:

```
select * from v$version;
```

results in

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

CORE    11.2.0.3.0  Production

TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like that:

http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-constants.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/constantvar_declaration.htm

```
declare
  id constant number := 2;
begin
  /* Some stuff here */
  ...
end;
```

Comment: I executed only the declare id constant number := 2; part. This results in the error message: [DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 2, Column 25:
PLS-00103: Found symbol "end-of-file" as expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

Comment: you should put something within `begin end` in Oracle; change `...` to `null;`

Comment: Well, as i said, I got an error from executing only the first two lines. It doesn't matter what's coming up next.

Comment: But now I execute the whole thing (with null) and then I get the error: [DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 2, Column 25:
PLS-00103: found symbol "end-of-file" as expecting one of the following:
   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
[BEGIN - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 3, Column 1:
PLS-00103: found symbol "END" as expecting one of the following:

   ;

Comment: You'd probably run the query in Sql Fiddle; I've run it at Oracle servers (11.2g) and this OK. Try `begin null; end;` this block doesn't go in Sql Fiddle as well.

Comment: declare myId varchar2(12);
begin
 select my_id into myId from tablename where number='0000001670';
end  STILL DOESN'T WORK

Comment: @Chris311 `number` is keyword in Oracle, put it in quotation marks when using as field: `"number"`. `declare myId varchar2(12); begin select my_id into myId from tablename where "number"='0000001670'`

Comment: Ok, the solution is to execute these lines buffered, and not line by line (which is standard for Sql Commander).

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MYCONSTANTS
IS 
   PI               CONSTANT REAL    := 3.14;     -- SQL data type
   MAX_DAYS_IN_YEAR CONSTANT INTEGER := 366;      -- SQL data type
   MINOR_ALLOWED    CONSTANT BOOLEAN := FALSE;    -- PL/SQL-only data type
END;
/
```

I would go with a *Package* based approach for defining all my constants. And you can access it like *Static* constants in java. In your `PL/SQL`. (Example: `MYCONSTANTS.PI`)

Comment: Executing this results in:  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.468 secs]  Command processed. No rows were affected
 [MAX_DAYS_IN_YEAR - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: invalid SQL-statement
 14:33:36  [MINOR_ALLOWED - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: invalid SQL-statement [END - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: invalid sql statement

Comment: Select the entire block and then execute it!